# Passes the first case but fails the other cases

Tags: python-3.x

Okay so I finished a code on hackerrank. It passes the test case but once I submit it fails the others. I have scanned through the code several times without a solution. Any thoughts on this? I have attached the screenshot of the question and my code as well as the test case scenarios that failed.

[image]

[image: Cases ran against]

My code:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def batting_stats(lst): 
rgh,rgf,totr,totbf,totd,crat = 0,0,0,0,0,0  #rgh: runs greater than 100, rgf: runs greater 50
                                            #totr:total runs, totbf:total balls faced, #totd: total 
                                            #dismissals, crat: conversion rate

results = []

for inning in lst:
    runs_scored = inning[0]
    balls_faced = inning[1] 
    dismissed = inning[-1] 

    totr += runs_scored
    totbf += balls_faced
    totd += dismissed

    if runs_scored >= 100:
        rgh += 1
    elif runs_scored == 50:
        rgf += 1

    average = totr // max(totd, 1)
    strikeRate = int((totr / totbf) * 100)  

    if rgf > 0:
        crat = ( rgh // rgf ) * 100

    results.append([average, strikeRate, crat])
return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

innings_count = int(input().strip())
innings = []

for _ in range(innings_count):
    innings_item = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    innings.append(innings_item)

result = batting_stats(innings)

for x in result or []:
    fptr.write(' '.join(map(str, x)))
    fptr.write('\n')     

fptr.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to your grader, but here are some obvious issues I see.

```
if runs_scored >= 100:
        rgh += 1
    elif runs_scored == 50:
        rgf +=1
```

should be

```
if runs_scored >= 100:
        rgh += 1
        rgf +=1 (because a 100 plus score is also a 50 plus score)
    elif runs_scored >= 50: (at least 50 is the condition not exactly 50)
        rgf += 1
```

Next,

```
 average = totr // max(totd, 1)
```

should be

```
          if totd==0:
           average=totr
          else:
           average=totr/totd
```

And,
`crat = ( rgh // rgf ) * 100` should be

```
crat = ( rgh / rgf ) * 100
```

I have included these edits together with a few more, and have tested this code on the one available input and a few others. It returns, as expected, a list of lists with numbers that match the expected output. Please try this out in the grader.

```
import math
def batting_stats(lst): 
 rgh,rgf,totr,totbf,totd,crat = 0,0,0,0,0,0 
 results = []

 for innings in lst:
    totr += innings[0]
    totbf += innings[1]
    totd += innings[2]

    if innings[0] >= 100:
        rgh += 1
        rgf +=1
    elif innings[0] >= 50:
        rgf+=1
    if totd==0:
           average=totr
    else:
           average=totr/totd
    strikeRate = (totr / totbf) * 100  

    if rgf > 0:
        crat = ( rgh / rgf ) * 100
    else:
        crat=0
    results.append([math.floor(average), math.floor(strikeRate), math.floor(crat)])
 return results
```

Comment: Thanks but same issue. If it helps, this is the grader system: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/comp1126-ex05-2019/challenges

Comment: Registration is required to see the page. Did you run only batting_stats with the changes? They ask for only batting_stats. I see there is extraneous stuff in the code.

Comment: tested it but the output is that of `30 50 0`  instead of the expected output mentioned before in the original post

Comment: I got [[12 50 0][30 50 0]] which is expected as per sample output 0 above. Did you feed the function to the grader? Did it pass the other test cases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201168/discussion-between-adam-newman-and-user2371765).